# How to access to an Azure App Insights output with "GetComponnectOutput" on Pulumi

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, pulumi, appinsights, pulumi-python

I created an Azure App Insights with Pulumi and with `GetComponnectOutput` I received the output like the below:

Sample Code:

```
app_insights_key = insights.get_component_output(
    resource_group_name=temp_resources_group.name,
    resource_name=temp_app_insights.name,
)

pulumi.export('the output is:', app_insights_key)
```

The Output is:

```
Outputs:
  + the output is:: {
      + app_id                             : "46470d16-bff3--b6fa8effc890"
      + application_id                     : "app-insights-temp112-gx"
      + application_type                   : "web"
      + connection_string                  : "InstrumentationKey=8418a8ce.com/"
      + creation_date                      : "2022-05-14T17:40:20.5340124+00:00"
      + disable_ip_masking                 : true
      + etag                               : "\"e800edf3-0000-0100-0000-627fe9860000\""
      + flow_type                          : "Bluefield"
      + id                                 : "/subscriptions/7bb4482f-3343-4b08"
      + ingestion_mode                     : "LogAnalytics"
      + instrumentation_key                : "8418a8cd-5700-7-3138752bd5f6"
```

I wanna access to `instrumentation_key` and try to use the below way:

```
app_key = app_insights_key["instrumentation_key"]
```

But I received an error.

```
 RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_component_output` return type is `Output[GetComponentResult]`, so you need to use `apply` to get its property:

```py
component = insights.get_component_output(
    resource_group_name="temp_resources_group.name",
    resource_name="temp_app_insights.name",
)

app_insights_key = component.apply(lambda c: c.instrumentation_key)
```

Read more in [Inputs/Outputs, Apply](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#apply).